# Fredholm elements of a Lie algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, operator-theory, fredholm-operators

An element $a$ of a Lie algebra $L$ is called a Fredholm element if the adjoint operator $\mathrm{ad}_a:L \to L$ is a Fredholm linear map. That is: its kernel is a finite-dimensional space and its range $\mathrm{ad}_a(L)$ is a finite-codimensional subspace.

Is there an infinite-dimensional Lie algebra with at least one Fredholm element? Is there a Lie algebra $L$ whose only non-Fredholm element is $0$?

Comment: Do you have an application—for Fredholm elements generally, or for these questions in particular—in mind (or does it already exist), or is this just a curiosity?

Comment: @LSpice I don't know if OP has a particular motivation, but I find the question very interesting and natural. Since we cannot expect $\mathrm{ad}_a$ to be invertible (for $L\neq 0$) the closest possible to invertibility would be being Fredholm. To each Lie algebra we can consider the group generated by Fredholm adjoint maps in the Fredholm automorphism group.

Comment: PS: by "Fredholm automorphism group" (of $L$, viewed as vector space only), I mean, the group $\mathrm{Fred}_L$ obtained as follows: the quotient of the monoid consisting of all Fredholm linear endomorphisms of $L$, by identifying $f,g$ if $f-g$ has finite rank. If the Lie algebra $L$ has infinite dimension and has the property that all nonzero elements are Frehdolm, then the map $L\smallsetminus\{0\}\to \mathrm{Fred}_L$ induced by $x\mapsto\mathrm{ad}_x$, is injective.

Comment: @LSpice  it was just a curiosity. In fact this question was not a part of  a research question or a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite-dimensional Lie algebra with basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ and brackets $[e_i,e_j]=(i-j)e_{i+j}$, over a field of characteristic zero, satisfies the required condition: every nonzero element is Fredholm.

First let me mention it's immediate that $\mathrm{ad}_{e_i}$ is Fredholm for every $i$. Denote by $V_k$ the subspace generated by $(e_i)_{i\le k}$.

Let $f$ be a nonzero element, say $f=\sum_{i=0}^ka_ie_i$ with $a_k\neq 0$ and $T=\mathrm{ad}_f$ (let's call $k$ the degree of $f$). Then the kernel of $T$ is contained in $V_k$ (indeed, if $g\notin V_k$, say of degree $\ell$, then $[f,g]$ has degree exactly $k+\ell$). Next computing $[f,e_i]$ for each $i\ge k+1$, we see by induction that $V_i/V_k$ is contained in the image of $p_k\circ T$, where $p_k$ is the projection $L\to L/V_k$. Hence $p_k\circ T$ is surjective. Hence $\mathrm{Im}(T)+V_k=L$, thus $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is finite-codimensional.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and very helpful information in your comments. I was not aware of this Lie structure and Fredholm automorphism group.

Comment: This Lie algebra is quite well-known (as 1-dimensional Witt Lie algebra). Here $e_n$ corresponds to the derivation $x^{n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. One can also consider it with $n\in\mathbf{Z}$; I think the arguments can be adapted, and the latter has a central extension (with 1-dimensional center) called Virasoro Lie algebra.